# Trouble with page reload. ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reload

So what i have is a web application that uses c# code and javascript code. My javascript code generates some information dependant on the users input. Once this is finished it is saved using a ASP button. Attached to the asp button is a on client click and a on click event. the Javascript code validates the code and makes sure that the string that has been created is valid. If not a error message is sent to a hidden label. The C# code then checks that label and if it is empty (if there was no problem with validation) it executes the C# code. If it has a value inside then the error message from the hidden label is passed to a visible label using the c# code and shown to the user.

However if the error message is shown the page in automatically reloaded (as it is a button click event this always happens). and the users inputs are cleared from the screen.

Is there any way i can stop the page from reloading when the error message is shown?

**CODE**

Javascript:

```
    if (goalnum > 0 && blocknum > 0 && playernum == 1 && goalnum == blocknum) {


        mapsave = JSON.stringify(map);
        document.getElementById('<%=mapsave.ClientID %>').value = mapsave;

    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('<%=lblError.ClientID %>').value = "Your map must have one and only one player, one or more blocks, one or more goals and the number of blocks must match up with the number of goals";
    }
```

C#

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (mapsave.Value.ToString() == "")
        {
            lblResult.Text = lblError.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            AddNodeToXMLFile("filepath.xml", "TileMaps");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you `return false` on the button click? If not, even if validation has failed a new Post will fire.

Can you post the code perhaps?

Comment: I have added the code above as an edit. As you can see in the javascript i am saving the map into a label called mapsave then if that label is empty then show the lblResult.Text. This is where i would like the error message to show but not reload the page as their information will be reset.

Comment: Ahh i have just realise how to do it... In my ASP button i had to add the retun element onto my onclientclick. And i had to add the return false; onto the if statement. Now it works. Thanks